# How to access device feature using html5 windows phone 8 application?

Tags: html, windows-phone-8

I have to create HTML5App in window phone 8.1 app.

Can you please assist me to handle the followings?

1. Which is best method to handle database (indexedDB or sqlite)
2. How can i access device feature from html5. i.e., phone gap or native c#. which one is suit for html5 app.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to create an HTML5 app I'd go with Cordova + sqlite

Comment: What type of "device features"? Some may already be available in WinJS. The "best" is subjective and depends on what you're trying to accomplish.